# Strawberry Shake Code Generation cannot resolve type reference 'None:Any'

Tags: c#, graphql, back4app, hotchocolate, strawberryshake

I try to use Strawberry Shake to generate Code from Querys in my Client.
I created a Demo Project and do all the Steps in the [Documentation](https://chillicream.com/docs/strawberryshake)
I can succesfull init it with this command `dotnet graphql init https://parseapi.back4app.com/graphql -n TestClient -p ./ConsoleApp1 --headers X-Parse-Application-Id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX --headers X-Parse-Master-Key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX --headers X-Parse-Client-Key= XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX --headers Content-Type=application/json`

But whenever I add a file and add a simple query and build the solution i get the error

```
"Unable to resolve type reference 'None:Any'."
```

And the code won't get generated.

I could run the same query on tools like https://graphiql-online.com/

I also tried to use other graphl servers to generate code. Everywhere i tried it, i could generate code from a query. Did anyone else running into this?

Edit: If i remove all lines in schema with type: any i can compile the code... is there a solution how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the Back4App Support we've found out the problem.
Rename in the local schema file all `Any` to `AnyType` or `String` afterwards the build is successfull and generate the code